# change event on form fields django

Tags: django

I got this called django form fields on a template sales.html :

```
<div class="center-panel">
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'cost_control_app:request_update' form_sale.instance.request %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="row">
                {%include "partials/field.html" with field=form_sale.item %}
                {%include "partials/field.html" with field=form_sale.usd_value %}
                {%include "partials/field.html" with field=form_sale.exchange_rate %}
                {%include "partials/field.html" with field=form_sale.euros_value %}
                {%include "partials/field.html" with field=form_sale.date %}
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I need that when i change the usd value field, the euros field update itself depending of the exchange rate field value and viceversa....is there a "onchange" event to call or something ??

Thanks for your help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is use JavaScript, to hook into the `change` event of the field. Assuming you're using the normal field name and ID conventions, something like this would work (presuming you're using jQuery):

```js
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $('#id_usd_value').on('change',
      function(e) {
        $('#id_euros_value').val(
          Math.round(
            parseFloat($(this).val()) * parseFloat($('#id_exchange_rate').val()) * 100
          ) / 100
        );
      }
    );

    $('#id_euros_value').on('change',
      function(e) {
        $('#id_usd_value').val(
          Math.round(
            parseFloat($(this).val()) / parseFloat($('#id_exchange_rate').val()) * 100
          ) / 100
        );
      }
    );
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id="id_usd_value">
  <input id="id_exchange_rate" type="hidden" value="0.92">
  <input id="id_euros_value">
</form>
```

This is a really crude example, using raw HTML, and making some assumptions about what your exchange-rate contains.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, can i set a name for every field inside the include tag and then use the jquery code ??

Comment: I tried your code exactly as it is, but it's not working =(

Comment: Re your first comment, Without knowing the HTML your include tag is providing, I'm not sure. Re the second, I made guesses based on what I'd seen. If you can paste the HTML that actually gets rendered to the page (ie: via "View Source") I might be able to amend my answer.

Comment: Solved it, upgraded to Jquery 2.1.4 and works like a charm. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, upgraded to Jquery 2.1.4 and works like a charm, thanks to all.